# `dispersiontest()` estimates dispersion too small

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, overdispersion

I am using `dispersiontest(fit, trafo=2)` from the AER package in R to see if my data is overdispersed and what the dispersion parameter $\alpha$ is. Since I use `trafo=2` I assume that $Var(y) = \mu + \alpha \cdot \mu^2$.

However, I get a dispersion parameter of about $0.4$, which is not at all in line with `mean(y) = 68` and `var(y) = 8124`, because obivously $68 + 0.4\cdot68^2 = 1917$. If I estimate $\alpha$ "by hand", i.e. just solving the above equation for $\alpha$, I get a value of $51$.

Could somebody explain why`dispersiontest` estimates $\alpha$ so small?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you don't estimate $\alpha$ by solving for it from the formula that models $Var(y)$ in terms of $\mu$. Instead $\alpha$ is estimated by analyzing how $Var(y)$ changes with $\mu$ *locally* in your data. It is *not* a value that comes from the *global* estimations of $Var(y)$ and $\mu$ but rather from its *local* estimations.

Measuring and using these local estimations to estimate $\alpha$ is done via regression, as explained in the Details section of the documentation of `dispersiontest()`:

> Overdispersion corresponds to alpha > 0 and underdispersion to alpha < 0. The coefficient alpha can be estimated by an auxiliary OLS regression and tested with the corresponding t (or z) statistic which is asymptotically standard normal under the null hypothesis.

Comment: thank you! I see what you mean, that means $Var(y) = \mu + \alpha \cdot \mu$ is just not generally correct? What exactly does "locally" mean here? For which datapoints is the equation true?

Comment: No, I don't mean that $Var(y) = \mu + \alpha * \mu^2$ is not generally correct. What I mean is that this formula proposes a relationship between $Var(y)$ and $\mu$ as when you propose a relationship between a dependent variable `y` and a variable `x`. The relationship is theoretical and is **estimated using regression** on the observed data points `(x,y)`.
Here is the same thing, you *locally* observe values of $Var(y)$ and $\mu$ ("local" means in a neighbourhood around each `x`) and estimate the relationship between $Var(y)$ and $\mu$ using regression.